# How to remove default links from SharePoint 2013 suite bar and add my own links

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement where I need to remove or hide the default links displayed in Suite Bar like NewsFeed, SkyDrive, Sites etc.  I want to add my own links and use this section as my Menu.

So while adding I want the items to be easily configurable by content editors. They can edit the links that needs to be shown and control the order. No hard coding of links.

If someone can help in this.

[image: Suite Bar Customisation]

Regards,
navish

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by oevrriding Delegate controls that displays these links. The below links will help

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I have followed the link to add custom link to Suite Bar but I am not able to see the Link On Suit Bar ? Any Idea what to change?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom delegate control that target the SuiteLinksDelegate ControlId.
Add it to a Farm-scoped feature to make the custom delegate control active in the whole farm.
If you do not like hard-coded links you can program against a custom SharePoint list that stores the configurable links.

To Add custom links you can use the approach described here: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages

If you need to remove some built-in links while keeping others (I had this requirement) you can use code like this:

```
    public partial class SuiteLinksDelegate : MySuiteLinksUserControl
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            // save for later
            var httpwriter = (writer.InnerWriter as HttpWriter);

            // hijack the innerwriter
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            writer.InnerWriter = tw;

            // call base
            base.Render(writer);

            // get the html
            var currentHtml = sb.ToString();
            XElement element = XElement.Parse(currentHtml);

            // remove SkyDrive link
            var suiteLinkNodes = element.Elements("li").ToArray();
            var remainingNodes = suiteLinkNodes.Where(node => !(node.ToString().Contains("ShellDocuments")));
            element.ReplaceNodes(remainingNodes);

            var modifiedHTML = element.ToString();

            // set back the old innerwriter
            writer.InnerWriter = httpwriter;

            // write delegate control html
            httpwriter.Write(modifiedHTML);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript approach to hide this links as described in below link

http://www.tuyrcorp.com/sharepoint-2013-top-links-name-id-and-how-to-hide-them/

you can also add new item in the dropdown using this same javascript as well

Hope this helps

Thanks